# How can i select different columns in a table only searching with specific words? Using the WHERE command\

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this

```
USE [database]
GO

SELECT * 
FROM [DBO.CHEKCLIST]
WHERE task_name = 'Verify event from'
GO
```

I expect to get all columns from Task_name that include the three words 'Verify event from'.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). (Please [edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `LIKE` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM [DBO.CHEKCLIST] WHERE task_name LIKE '%Verify event from%'
```